# How to know the name/ID of window in focus

Tags: c++, windows, opencv

How to know the name/ID of window in focus specifically in OpenCV.
Is there any event handling/callback or windows api that make this possible if it is not possible with OpenCV.
I am working on Windows 7 and 8.1.
I want to do something similar to (but not limited to):

> If a window is in focus, and some event like mouse or key press happens,
>   then update that particular window

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Kris, there exists a solution on window. Use windows api to take handle of active window as using:

```
HWND WINAPI GetActiveWindow(void);
```

Now use `GetWindowText()` function to extract out title, if any. It may not be portable. There should exist similar api for other OS.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I don't know if windows or any other api can help.
I have an idea to take screen-shot, somehow, and then use opencv itself for image processing. Assumption is that the focused window will be on the top and most focused so we can see the name easily. We can process color to separate focused window from others, if any. And using OCR to extract windows name.

Comment: This would never be robust. Why not just use native API s to get the active window?